# Transient Behaviour Transient Property Lorenz Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, chaos-theory

Was reading Lorenz paper "Deterministic Nonperiodic Flow" and it says that if a trajectory is not a fixed point, periodic orbit or quasi-periodic orbit and no transient behaviour then it is a non-periodic flow.

I am still a bit unsure what a transient behaviour/property is.

Can anyone please explain what a transient behaviour/property is to me in a undergraduate mathematics level?

Comment: This paper is the first numerical study of a strange attractor. There were books written at the time, fifty years ago, called  "Transients in Linear Systems", I've forgotten the authors.  It was a significant problem for an engineer, finding the unstable , transient behavior as it applied to amplifiers and electronic circuits. In this paper Lorenz finds a whopper and doesn't know what to call it. Eventually the name "Strange Attractor" was coined. Was it Floris Takens and David Ruelle, yes, I think so.

Comment: @Alan: Thank you Alan, I meant that I am not sure what a transient behaviour/property is.

Comment: The response of an electric circuit when the power is turned on might be an example of a transient. I searched for "transients in linear systems" --  the book I was thinking of basically uses the Laplace Transform to solve ODEs that model electrical circuits.

Comment: He is interested in long term behavior of the system. So the best guess here is that he is referring to transient part of trajectory which occurs before settling down to : fixed point, periodic or quasiperiodic orbit.